# Client side compression with HTML5 and Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

Am working on a web application and we allow users to upload files to our server. Am trying to do client side compression before uploading files to the server. What would be the better way to achieve this using HTML5 and JavaScript.

Thanks.

Comment: Telling the user to only upload zipped files. :) Can you actually zip files using javascript?  doubt it since it has to be done throu

Comment: It is possible. See my answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The common mechanism to do what you want is using [FileReader](http://caniuse.com/#search=filereader) and a JavaScript client-side compression library (i.e. [compressjs](https://github.com/cscott/compressjs)).

Answer (score 2):

In 2022 it's almost too simple, if the browser [supports](https://caniuse.com/?search=compressionstream) [CompressionStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CompressionStream), [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) and [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response).

In the example below I use `FormData` to collect all the fields from the form.
Then I use the readable stream from the file, and pipe it though the compression stream. Then I use `Response` to read everything from the compressed stream and return it in a blob.

```js
async function compress(file, encoding = 'gzip') {
  try {
    return {
      data: await new Response(file.stream().pipeThrough(new CompressionStream(encoding)), {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': file.type
        },
      }).blob(),
      encoding,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    // If error, return the file uncompressed
    console.error(error.message);
    return {
      data: file,
      encoding: null
    };
  }
}

theForm.addEventListener(
  'submit',
  (event) => event.preventDefault()
)

theForm.addEventListener(
  'input',
  async function(event) {
    // collect all fields
    const fd = new FormData(theForm);

    // Get 'file handle' from imput elemen
    const file = fd.get('theFile');
    if (!file) return

    const encoding = fd.get('theEncoding');
    const compressed = await compress(file, encoding);

    theMessage.value = [
      'Compressed with', compressed.encoding,
      'Source file was', file.size, 'bytes',
      'and the compressed file', compressed.data.size,
      'saving', ((1 - compressed.data.size / file.size) * 100)
      .toFixed(0),
      '%.'
    ].join(' ')
  }
)
```

```css
form>* {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form id="theForm">
  <select name="theEncoding">
    <option>gzip</option>
    <option>deflate</option>
    <option>deflate-raw</option>
  </select>
  <input type="file" name="theFile" id="theFile">

</form>
<output id="theMessage"></output>
```